# Generate Nested Map from Path String in dart

Tags: dart

I want to create a map using the path

```
generateNestedMap("foo.bar.baz", "someValue")
```

and the output should be

```
Output: {'foo'{'bar':{'baz': 'someValue'}}}
```

Comment: Can you explain further what part of the problem you're having the most trouble with? Are you ok with splitting the string by periods?  And nesting the map from the inside out by reversing the split order of the strings?

Comment: not able to understand how to use recursion

Comment: doesn't require recursion... Just a for loop

Answer (score 1):

Run this in dartpad.  No recursion required.  Just build it from inside-out:

```
void main() {
  print(generateNestedMap("foo.bar.baz", "someValue"));
}

Map generateNestedMap(String path, String payload) {
  
  var steps = path.split('.');
  Object result = payload;
  for (var step in steps.reversed) {
    result = {step : result};
  }
  return result as Map;

}
```

EDIT: Or, as I suggested in one of the comments, a little fancier, but cool:

```
void main() {
  print(generateNestedMap("foo.bar.baz", "someValue"));
}

Map generateNestedMap(String path, String payload) {
  var steps = path.split('.');
  var result = steps.reversed.fold(payload, (old, next) => {next: old});
  return result as Map;
}
```

Comment: for functional programmers you can also try: result = steps.reversed.fold(result, (old, next) => {next : old});